# Efficient way to tokenize conditionally

Tags: c#, string, tokenize

Given user input string:

"Mainframes/pl/ sql; Software Testing/PL/SQL/Project management/"

What would be a good way to tokenize the string such that '/' is retained if it is part of "PL/ SQL", but not otherwise, giving tokens:

"Mainframes", "pl/ sql", "Software Testing", "PL/SQL", "Project management"

This is because users may accidentally enter the '/' character as a separator.

Answer (score 1):

If the order of the tokens isn't important then something like this might work:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Tokenise()
{
    var input = "Mainframes/pl/ sql; Software Testing/PL/SQL/Project management/";
    var results = new List<string>();

    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"pl\s*/\s*sql", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        results.Add(match.Value);
    }

    input = Regex.Replace(input, @"pl\s*/\s*sql", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    results.AddRange(input.Split(new []{'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

    return results;
}
```

This starts by searching for the pl/sql tokens (accounting for differences in whitespace and capitalisation) then strips them out of the input string and performs a simple split on the remaining '/' characters. The downside is that the order of the tokens will be different from the input string.